# Format current Date with time as Date, not as String

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, format

I try to parse the currenct date and time in a Date variable to store the value in a sql database (datetime).

I have tried this, but get a error:

```
Dim dDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(CType(Date.Now, String), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Here is the parte for the sql parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@DATUMERSTELLUNG", dDate))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no parsing to do. `Date.Now` is the current date and time as a `Date`.  That's it.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATUMERSTELLUNG", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date.Now
```

Comment: Yes that is correct. Thanks :) sometimes it is as easy as it could be.